# Prove $(x, y) \mapsto \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y$ is surjective

Tags: functions

> $f$ is defined  by:$$f: \mathbb{N^2} \to \mathbb{N}$$
>   $$(x, y) \mapsto \frac{(x+y)(x+y+1)}{2}+y$$
>   Prove that $f$ is surjective.

What I have about $f$:

1. $\forall (x,y)\in\mathbb{N^*×N} : f(x-1, y+1)-f(x,y) = 1$
2. $\forall y\in\mathbb{N}: f(y+1, 0)-f(0,y) = 1$
3. $f$ is injective.

And if possible how can I find a solution to an equation like this:

$$f(x,y)=2018$$

Comment: Does your $\mathrm N$ include $0$?

Comment: Probably yes, as he used $\mathbb{N}^*$ at one point

Comment: It is sufficient to show that $(x+y)(x+y+1)$ cannot be odd for arbitrary choices of $x,y\in\mathrm N.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what you have already showed it can by done by induction.

**Indcution hypothesis:** for $n$ there exists a pair $(x,y)$ such that $f(x,y) = n$.

**Induction start:**
$f(0,0) = 0$.

**Induction step:** Let $n$ and $(x,y)$ be according to the induction hypothesis. Then there two cases:

1. $x\neq 0$: So by item 1. of what you have already showed
   $$f(x-1,y+1) = f(x,y) +1 = n+1.$$
2. $x=0$: Then by item 2. of what you have already showed
   $$f(y+1,0) = f(0,y) + 1 = n+1.$$

So in any case the induction hypothesis also holds for $n+1$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $z \in \mathbb N$. The sequence $u_n =\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ is strictly increasing and $u_0=0$. Therefore, it exists a unique $n\in \mathbb N$ such that

$$u_n \le z < u_{n+1}$$

You’ll verify that $f(n-z+u_n,z-u_n) =z$. As $0\le z-u_n <n+1$ we have $n-z+u_n \ge 0$. Consequently, $n-z+u_n$ and $z-u_n$ are both non negative proving that $f$ is surjective.

Apply that to $2018$. You have
$$u_{63} = 2016 \le 2018 < u_{64} =2080$$
And $f(61, 2)=2018$.

Comment: It is worth to mention that $u_{n+1} - u_n = n +1$ so the arguments for $f$ are always non negative.

Comment: @NathanaelSkrepek Good point! I’ll update the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear:  What you want to prove is that for any integer $k \ge 0$ there are integers $x,y \ge 0$ so that $\frac {(x+y)(x+y+1)}2 + y = k$.

(This assumes $0\in \mathbb N$.  Now some text have $0\not \in \mathbb N$.  I actually prefer that and think it is more ...er... natural.  But if $x \ge 1$ and $x \ge 1$ then $\frac {(x+y)(x+y+1)}2 + y \ge 2$ and we can't ever have $f(x,y) = 1$.))

So... to the problem...

Trick is (maybe) to realize that $\frac {(x+y)(x+y+1)}2 = \sum_{j=0}^{x+y} j$.

Now $0\le 0 < 0+1$ and $0+1 \le 1,2 < 0+1+2$ and $0+1+2 \le 3,4,5 < 0+1+2+3$ and so on.

For any $k$ there is a (unique) $M\in \mathbb N$ so that $\sum_{j=0}^{M} j \le k < \sum_{j=0}^{M+1} j$

If we let $y = k - \sum_{j=0}^{M} j = k-\frac {M(M+1)}2\ge 0$ we know that $\sum_{j=0}^{M} j \le k < \sum_{j=0}^{M+1} j$ so $0 \le y =k - \sum_{j=0}^{M} j < M+1$.  So if we let $x = M-y\ge 0$ we have

$f(x,y) = \frac {(x+y)(x+y+1)}2 + y$ =

$\frac {M(M+1)}2 + (k- \sum_{j=0}^{M} j) =$

$\sum_{j=0}^{M} j + (k- \sum_{j=0}^{M} j)=k$.

Furthermore we have proven that $x,y$ are unique so $f$ is a bijection.

This is basically the "diagonal" bijection.

$(0,0)\to 0\ \ \ \color{blue}{(0,1)\to 2}\ \ \ \color{green}{(0,2)\to 5}\ \ \ \color{red}{(0,3)\to 9}\ \ \ .....$

$\color{blue}{(1,0)\to 1}\ \ \ \ \color{green}{(1,1)\to 4}\ \ \ \color{red}{(1,2)\to 8}....$

$\color{green}{(2,0)\to 3}\ \ \ \color{red}{(2,1)\to 7}...$

$\color{red}{(3,0)\to 6}\ \ \ ....$

$....$

P.S. 1: If you don't have the insight that $\frac {(x+y)(x+y+1)}2 = \sum^{x+y} j$ you can reason that for every $k$ there is a unique $M$ so that $\frac {M(M+1)}2 \le k < \frac {M(M+1)}2 + (M+1)=\frac {(M+1)(M+2)}2$ but that's not so obvious.

However it is clear if $M = x+y$ the $\frac {M(M+1)}2$ is strictly increasing so that for all $k$ there is a unique $M$ so that $\frac {M(M+1)}2 \le k \le \frac {(M+1)(M+2)}2$ si this is surjective.  But without noting that $\frac {(M+1)(M+2)}2 = \frac {M(M+1)}2 + M+1$ *exactly* it's not so clear this is injective.

And there is no intuition that this is the "diagonal" mapping (which is *geometrically* obvious... but algebraicly nerve wracking.)

Although to be fair you didn't ask about proving it was injective.

P.S. 2:  If you require that $0\not \in N$ we can modify $f((x,y)) = [\frac {((x-1)+(y-1))((x-1)+(y-1)-1)}2 + (y-1)] + 1 = \frac {(x+y-2)(x+y-1)}2 + y$ to get the proper offset for the proper diagonal argument to be a bijection between $\mathbb N^2 \to \mathbb N$.

Answer (score 0):

Solving an equation like $f(x,y) = 2018$ wouldn't be too hard using your first two results. Start with $x = y = 1$ so $f(x,y) = 4$. Then, you know $f(0,2) = 5$ (through 1.), then use your 2nd result to obtain $f(3,0) = 6$ and, by using 1 again, $f(0,3) = 9$ and $f(4,0) = 10$. Via induction, prove that $f(n,0) = \sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ and then deduct that $f(n-l,l) = l+\sum_{k=1}^n k$ for $0 \leq l \leq n$. Since every natural number $n$ can be expressed as $n = l + \sum_{k=1}^m k$ for $0 \leq l \leq m$ and some natural $m$ (you might want to prove this too), this proves surjectivity.